# Updating column in df with dict type value in spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to updated a df column with a dict value using the following code:

```
for x in tmp_list:
   name = x.get('name')
   value = x.get('value')
   df = df.withColumn(name, func.lit(value))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.HashMap {updated_at=1661514003}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:88)
```

What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Considering your `tmp_list`  is a list of dictionaries, the code looks ok to me. Looks like some data error. Can you show the `tmp_list` here?

Comment: Yes `tmp_list` is a list of dictionaries. Eg: `[{'name':'col1','value':11}]` @derFotik

Comment: to debug the code, print the dict (`x`) in the loop. the code looks fine and works for your sample list of dict.

Comment: The type of value seems not simple value.